# Included Excluded region in Jenkins with Bitbucket server checkout

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-git-plugin

I want to understand how include region and exclude region works for [GIT Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/)
For my jenkins job setup, I have BitBucket server SCM checkout set and I am added an included path.

This is the only path for which I want to trigger a build.
However, this setup does not seem to work.

What I noticed is BitBucket payload does not have changeset files. Could that be the reason why?

How does this include/ exclude option work internally?